# Why does OSPF function on Network Layer whereas RIP functions on Transport Layer?

Tags: routing, ospf, rip

As far as I know, OSPF creates its messages directly at the network layer, whereas RIP function on UDP. Their function is pretty similar, so why is there such a difference in their messaging practice?

Comment: Two different people, at two different times, had two different ideas.

Comment: "_OSPF creates its messages directly at the network layer_" It would be more accurate to say that OSPF and EIGRP have their own transport protocols, where RIP uses UDP as its transport protocol, and BGP uses TCP as its transport protocol. The network layer is IP, and IP doesn't know anything about OSPF or the other routing protocols.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's simply no advantage in using UDP.

OSPF is designed to be implemented on hardware devices. Doing away with the (slight) UDP overhead reduces the implementation footprint and makes the traffic more efficient.

RIP was designed when routers were software implementations on hosts that had a full stack anyway.